# Laravel / Php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to create a regular which checks if an input field has ü,ä or ö.

If the input field has for instance the letter ü I want to switch it to ue.

So far I have this:

```
public static $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|max:30'
    'filename' => 'required|max:30|regex:/'
    ];
```

But I do not know how to further go on.

Comment: Try creating new validation function and use here;

Comment: Perhaps a better way to do this would be to create a custom sanitize method that your form data is passed through before validating it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep all the validation within the `Request class`, you could place the sanitation above the rules themselves; you can also abstract the top part into a method in order to keep your code cleaner.

```
$string = Request::get('filename');
$pattern = '/[ü]/';
$replacement = 'ue';
$newFileName = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
Request::merge(array('filename' => $newFileName));

public static $rules = [
  'email' => 'required|max:30',
  'filename' => 'required|max:30'
  ];
```